# How to convert ARKit SCNNode object location SCNVector3 to latitude and longitude?

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, arkit

I am adding a SCNNode with text, and I want to save its location, so that next I can show that added object on to map.

I can get node position using SCNVector3. Please help me how to convert it in latitude and longitude.

Thanks

Comment: I think now the question is more clear. I want @rmaddy you to make this question active. If you don't know the answer let other to give answer. if still you don't understand the question, you need to brush up your knowledge.

Comment: @bartektartanus I see your profile and you didn't mention anything about iOS and ARKIT, Then how you down voted my question without any knowledge about ARKIt and iOS

Answer (score 3):

There are ways to do what you seem to be asking about, but most of them are probably *overdoing* it.

ARKit and geolocation/mapping technologies (CoreLocation, MapKit) really operate on different scales.

- ARKit works at room scale—that is, it’s hard to do anything meaningful within a single AR session that involves distances above 10-20 meters—and has precision/error on the order of millimeters.
- Geolocation, by definition, operates at planet scale, and has precision/error ranging from one to several meters depending on factors in the local environment (cellular AGPS and WiFi location availability, satellite visibility, radio noise, position-refining features like iBeacon, etc).

In other words, almost any virtual content you can accurately place in an AR session is probably so close to you that its distance from your geolocated position is smaller than the error in your geolocated position. (For example, ARKit might think your position within a room is stable, letting you place virtual content 1.5m in front of you. But while you’re doing that, your estimated geolocation is drifting around back and forth within a 5m radius.)

So, if you want to put a marker on a world map for your ARKit content, you’ll probably have an easier time ignoring that distance — just use your current position from CoreLocation as the marker.

---

If your app is for use only in a controlled environment (retail store, museum, etc) where you can ensure high-precision geolocation (say, by deploying iBeacons), you might be able to do something useful with that distance. Translating positions from ARKit world space to lat/long is pretty simple regardless, but you have to be in a situation like this for the result to be meaningful:

1. Use the `gravityAndHeading` world alignment option for your AR session, so that the x/z axes of ARKit world coordinate space line up with world compass directions.
2. Project the distance vector between the camera and an object in AR space into 2D (x/z) to get east/west and north/south distance along Earth’s surface in meters relative to the user’s position.
3. Get the user’s position in geographic space from CoreLocation, and add the vector you got in step 2 to get the object’s position in geographic space. (`CLLocationCoordinate2D` doesn’t do meters, so you may find it useful to convert through another space like `MKMapPoint` to get a final result.)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! I just started digging into the possibilities of combining the 2 technologies and you are spot on.

Mentioning the gravityAndHeading alignment option is a lifesaver. I did not realize that existed and have been spending the last week or two trying to figure out that math.